# Maven cannot resolve symbol "@Transactional" Intellij Idea

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

Estoy trabajando con Java, Springboot y Maven en Intelllij Idea, pero tengo un problema cuando intento utilizar la anotación **@Transactional**, me dice que debo agregar la dependencia en Maven, pero cuando la agrego el error persiste. Espero alguien pueda ayudarme con el problema, me encuentro atorado. Adjunto imagen del error y el POM que utilizo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

POM:

***

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
3.1.5
 

com.Java1
e1
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
war
e1
Demo project for Spring Boot

<java.version>11</java.version>

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.13</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Ya intenté re instalar Maven, cambiar las dependencias manualmente, probar diferentes versiones del JDK e incluso con proyectos nuevos en blanco y no funciona.

Comment: Saludos, el idioma del sitio es el Español, por favor traduce tu pregunta. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes agregar la dependencia en tu `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
  <version>5.3.22</version>
</dependency>
```

solo así podrás usar el import

```
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
```

si por alguna razón decidieras usar [spring-data](/questions/tagged/spring-data) podrías usar este otro:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!
Con eso se solucionó mi problema! :D
Utilicé la primer dependencia (spring-tx)